# Bedeutung zu-/beimessen

Tags: word-choice

Gibt es Unterschied zwischen "zu" und "bei" in diesem Fall, oder werden sie synonym verwendet? Beisp.

> Alle Staaten können durch ihren Beitritt zeigen, dass sie der militärischen Vertrauensbildung und Rüstungskontrolle mehr Bedeutung **zumessen**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es kommt darauf an.

In der Wendung *Bedeutung beimessen/zumessen* wird man keinen Unterschied sehen; *beimessen* und *zumessen* sind hier austauschbar.

> ... unterschiedliche Bedeutungen, welche die Parteien der Rolle der
>   Zivilgesellschaft **beimessen/zumessen**
>
> Aufgrund der hohen Bedeutung, die wir dem Thema Umwelt seit langem **beimessen/zumessen**, haben wir in den vergangenen Jahren ein umfassendes Umweltmanagement-System implementiert.
>
> Selbst wenn die maßgeblichen Verkehrskreise diesem Bildelement irgendeine Bedeutung **zumessen/beimessen** würden, gälte gleiches für die grafische Gestaltung des "Q" in der benutzten...
>
> Außerdem hat die Klägerin sich mit der Behauptung begnügt, der Begriff buy sei ungenau und schwammig, und nicht vorgetragen, welche andere Bedeutung als die eines günstigen Verhältnisses zwischen Preis und Verkehrswert der Dienstleistungen die maßgebenden Verkehrskreise dem Wortzeichen Best Buy **beimessen/zumessen** könnten.

Gleichwohl würde ich dem Wort *beimessen* eine größere Häufigkeit der Verwendung **zusprechen** - nicht aber <strike>**beisprechen**</strike>.

Es gibt aber auch Wendungen, wo beimessen/zumessen nicht ausgetauscht werden können:

> Staatsanwalt: "Das Gericht sollte diesem Vergehen folgende Strafe **zumessen**: Sechs Tagessätze wegen..."